How to pass a variable behind a quoted statement?
I have this code:
(defun my-test (type)
    
       (org-roam-ql-nodes-files '(and (properties "TYPE" (format "%s" type)))))
    
(my-test "wiki")

It throws a type error as follows

Debugger entered–Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp (format “%s” type))
string-match((format “%s” type) “manual” nil)

As you see the (format "%s" type) statement is passed as is to a subsequent (string-match) macro. I tried many different approaches, but ultimately, the ' in (org-roam-ql-nodes-files '(...)) prevents any transformation I attempted like wrapping it in a (quote ...) macro, adding a let statement to transform the type variable beforehand...
Is there a way in Elisp to work around this problem ?
Thanks in advance.
=== EDIT ===
After hitting this wall for quite a while, I finally got the answer from an LLM :) I have not read the doc yet to fully understand the code, but this works with a backquote:
(defun my-test (type)
  (let ((query `(and (properties "TYPE" ,type))))  ; Use backquote and comma to evaluate type
     (org-roam-ql-nodes-files query)))



It never rains but it pours :-) Check out this question asked yesterday!

You are right, those questions/answers are related. I have missed them I guess. To be honest, I am not even sure I would have really understood how to apply them to my case if I had found them. Even after geting a working solution, and skimming through the doc, I am still very shaky on that syntax. I need  to read a lot more seriously about it, and actually use it a few times I guess. Anyway, I edited after finding a solution right away, it can always help others to have practical examples. In the same spirit, thanks for pointing to more of them.

Yes, there are many different questions all with the same solution: that's why, even though it is a FAQ, there are so many duplicates. That's why it is important to mark each new such question as a duplicate and link it to the canonical answer. You can then get from that to all the linked questions by using a link like this:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7481 where 7481 is the id of the canonical question. There are 67 questions linked to it (!), not all of them duplicates (although some of those should be so marked).
